# SQL: How to insert records into another table based on values already there for a different value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one  table has the companynumbers and the second table has companynumbers and States (2 Columns). The second table has a list of all states that apply to the this one company.

Here is what I am trying to do: I am trying to insert other companies from the first table into the second table with the same states as the company that already exists.

First table:

```
  Company
  ----------
  TEST
  TEST3
  TEST4
  TEST5
```

Second table:

```
  Company | State
  --------+-------
  Test    | NY
  TEST    | PA
  TEST    | MI
```

How would I insert TEST with the same states that already exist for company "TEST"?

Answer (score 1):

So just a quick and dirty insert would work in your case.

```
Insert Into SecondTable (Company, State)
Select c.Company, st.State
From FirstTable c
Inner join SecondTable st
    on st.Company = 'test'
```